# USB audio on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

I just bought headphones with a USB-C plug instead of a typical jack. They work fine, but the sound range is all in-between the last increment. For instance when I use my F2(-) and F3(+) keys for sound, I'll hear nothing until the very last increment, at which it's gonna be way to loud all of a sudden.

I digged around a bit, and I saw a post that said "check your PCM settings in `alsamixer`", which I did, and I can see that before the last increment my PCM is at 0, and on the last increment it turns up to 100. If I control the volume through the PCM setting in `alsamixer` everything is smooth (25% is what I expect to be 25%), but it's quite inconvenient, how can I remap the master so that 0 on the master is 0 on the PCM, so that I can use my function keys?

### Screenshots:

##### PCM: 0%, Master: 96%

[image: alsamixer: PCM: 0%]
[image: settings: System Volume: 96%]

##### PCM: 25%, Master: 97%

[image: alsamixer: PCM: 25%]
[image: settings: System Volume: 97%]

Note: I just guessed that the offset is 96% for easy math, but as you can see from the pictures it's close to that.

Note 2: I did update & upgrade before posting.

Note 3: If I raise the volume on the PCM setting, it's gonna follow a proportional pattern (e.g. PCM: 50% - Master: 98%, PCM: 75% - Master: 99%, PCM: 100% - Master: 100%), which is why I think it's an offset problem, I just don't want to raise it above 25% to protect the headphones.